# Did I write that question?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

[On stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34537/acidzombie24) I wrote yesterday (Monday Oct 5th, its the 6th now) a question about signing in with google. I don't see it in my recent history, it is as if I never wrote it. Did the question/post go through or not? (I am hoping someone who can see deleted questions can check for me and see why)

-edit-
It turns out when I went to bed and awoke in the morning it was deleted because I didn't reread and rushed it in order to get sleep. Here it is again except I added the word implement into the title and considered the fact people might think actually logging in and not implementation (lol. Thats funny to me.)
[How do i implement ‘sign in with google’ on my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527947/how-do-i-implement-sign-in-with-google-on-my-site)

Comment: my you have asked a few questions haven't you?

Comment: @Rich Wow, you were not kidding. That profile description though is... yah.

Comment: I'd ask you to accept an answer for this question; but we all know you don't do that. (grin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was migrated here to meta via the normal means, and the deleted by Mr. Atwood himself.

10K users or mods only:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/how-do-i-sign-in-with-google

First rule of StackOverflow: you don't talk about stackoverflow.

---

> Would you be kind enough to paste or email me my question?

There's not much to it.  Giving you back the exact text won't help you.  You'll need to re-word things or asking it again will result in the same fate.  But you've been around SO long enough you *ought* to know that.  That said:

---

> I want to sign in using a google account? (not openid... i 'll plan to use openid only if this doesnt have much benefits). I notice a few sites can login via google and i am wondering how.

Comment: I don't see it there. Was it deleted?

Comment: Looks like it was migrated, then deleted.

Comment: Original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523262/how-do-i-sign-in-with-google-closed

Comment: amusingly the OP doesn't mention SO, it appears to be a valid question about OpenID that's worded to look a bit like it refers to logging into SO

Comment: @Rich - The OP didn't mention much of anything. It looked like a very unclear and poorly worded question, and I don't know how anyone got anything out of it.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to paste or email me my question? my email is thisUserName@gmail.com (or look in my profile)

Comment: Does the link not work for you? It should, since it's your question.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I cant use google cache either since it doesnt exist.

Comment: @mmyers: Those with under 10k rep can only see their own answers that have been deleted, not their questions.

Comment: Interesting. Why would that be? Is it because all the answers are deleted also, so it wouldn't be useful anyway?

Comment: @mmyers: I don't know. I'd guess the inconsistency comes from the addition of the 10k tools at a later time than the deleted post visibility rules were set for regular users.

Comment: ahh kyle! can you email me my question?

Comment: @acidzombie24: OK, sent you a copy of your deleted question.

Comment: bawhahaha. Hilarious. I guess i assumed being on stackoverflow would implied i am a programmer trying to do it programmatically. I really should reread, that was embarrassing. I can see how distracted i was yesterday while reading that. At least it was short and straight to the point.

Comment: In case you guys were wondering heres my revised question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527947/how-do-i-implement-sign-in-with-google-on-my-site

Comment: Better, but it would help if you'd tagged the question with your web dev platform.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you left out some vital information in your question. It was perceived to be a question like "how do I log in to *Stackoverflow*" when I believe your real question was "how do make my own website utilize Google's OpenID"?

You can ask the question again and try to add some detail like platform, language, etc. instead of a completely general one.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, it was migrated because several people (myself included) thought it pertained to signing in to Stack Overflow using a Google account. Several commenters (and answerers) thought that it referred to adding functionality to a website for signing in with a Google account. If this is what you meant, you can ask your question again, but please be clearer, because I don't see how anyone thought you meant that.

Comment: oops. was sleepy and in a rush. Yeah i meant on my own website.

Comment: I was going to go and vote to undelete, but since it was migrated, it's locked also.

Comment: @acidzombie - My apologies for helping kill your question. Use clearer words next time, and I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Not a problem, i would like to reask my question and i am very curious at how i worded it yesterday. Would you be kind enough to copy/paste it to me? via paste site or email? ? (my email is thisUserName@gmail.com or look in my profile)

Comment: now i am curious at the replies...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to view it, even if it were on SO (473 points away). Sorry I can't help you.